# What do i need for "idsldapmodify, ldapmodify,etc"?

Tags: ldap, tds

i want to use the ldap interface to modify some attributes at TDS.
I found a tutorial [Overriding password policy and unlocking accounts](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVJJU_6.4.0/com.ibm.IBMDS.doc_6.4/ds_ag_apndix_pwd_policy_override.html)

I created a .Ldif file and tried to load the file via command-line in Windows 7 (!). But i think i am missing the necessary ldap tools.

```
"idsldapmodify" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What do i exactly need to run such parameters "idsldapmodify –?"

Best regards!

Comment: You need IBM Directory Server (`ids`) for `idsldapmodify`, as that's what your link is about. Otherwise you should try using the standard `ldapmodify` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was the problem, "ldapmodify" didn't work. 
But now i got it. I have downloaded "OpenLDAP 2.4.34" and now i can use "ldapmodify". Thank your very much!